# Replace mysql field with X

Tags: mysql

I would like to update a MySQL database table column with *x*. How would I be able to do this without having to do so interactively from the `mysql>` prompt? I want to do this with one simple command.

Comment: If you don't login to the database you can't access it. If you can't access it you can't make the change.

Comment: I meant do it with one line command. Login with user/pass and command also

Comment: Please [update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/206103/edit) to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

You could execute the `mysql` command with `-e` option, like this:

```
$ mysql -u user -pPASSWORD -e 'UPDATE QUERY;'
```

From `man mysql`

```
--execute=statement, -e statement
Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that
produced with --batch. See Section 4.2.4, “Using Options on the
Command Line”, for some examples. With this option, mysql does not use
the history file.
```

Give a try!

**NOTE: Is not advisable to put the password in line**